# 'webkitMovementX' is deprecated. Please use 'movementX' instead

Tags: javascript

I am getting the above warning when trying to run my app in ionic. I am using google chrome as a browser.

Comment: pretty straight forward ... use `movementX` instead of `webkitMovementX`

Comment: Could you please explain what is webkitMovementX?

Comment: I'm assuming it's somewhere in your code. I may have misunderstood the question as it's just tagged javascript, did not think you were using any javascript libraries ... by the way, that's not an **error** that's a **warning** - so, shouldn't stop anything from working (yet)

Comment: "_please help_" With what? A warning was issued, it told you the problem, it told you the solution... what else could there be?

Comment: @JaromandaX, the app is running but some of the functions arent working

Comment: And what did you find out when you stepped through the code in your debugger?

Comment: When a new API is not fully standardized most browsers implement slightly different version of said API's with browsers specific prefixes. In this case `webkit`. When it become properly rooted those prefixes are removed and you can use the standardized API so in this case `movementX `. So either you or a library you use is still using the browser specific experimental API. You need to either update that library or your code. I do not know what API this is specifically but its usually the case.

Answer (score 2):

There's been a few other people who've been having that same issue too with the new version of Chrome:

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/4259

At first it appears the issue is coming from the Ionic libraries. However - at least according to the Ionic developers - it's mostly a generic Chrome warning and they're not using any instance of webkitMovementX in their libraries. So there's nothing to 'fix'.